# need a solution to the canonical form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I reduced the wave equation in cylindrical coordinates assuming to grab only the radial solutions and have arrived at the following.

$2(\xi+\eta)u_{\xi\eta}+u_{\xi}+u_{\eta}=0$, where $\xi=r+ct, \eta=r-ct$.

hereafter, I wasn't able to solve this. can someone bail me out?.

Answer (score 0):

I guess $ln(\xi+\eta)$ qualifies to be a solution. However I don't find any arbitrary function associated. I understand this is just $ln r$ which is a solution to the laplacian except at the origin and the time derivatives gets killed due to the absence of $t$. However this seems to be a wayward way to look I feel because this seems to be a particular class of solutions, namely the harmonic ones. can you help me?.